# Smelt vs smelled

Tags: verbs

Both are past tense verbs of smell, are they interchangeable? Are there right and wrong ways to use them in sentences, examples would be much appreciated too!

Comment: *Smelt* is obscure in AmE - except in the child's admonition: "He who *smelt* it, dealt it."

Comment: @Oldbag could you elaborate? What does AmE mean? Thank you! 

Comment: Curious history: [ngram of "smelt the metal" vs "smelt the odor"](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smelt+the+metal%2Csmelt+the+odor&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmelt%20the%20metal%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmelt%20the%20odor%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Davo it really caught on in the 1890s!

Comment: AmE - American English. In BrE, you'd be more likely to come across *smelt*, as in:  "The beauty parlour smelt of burning hair."

Comment: In the US, *smelt* is in rapid decline, but it is more likely with bad stuff. He smelled coffee, but smelt gas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As suggested by the [Grammarist](http://grammarist.com/spelling/smelled-smelt/) “smelled” is the  more common form in AmE, while in BrE both forms are used:

> ***In American and Canadian English, the verb smell makes smelled in the past tense and as a past participle.***
>
> ***Outside North America, English speakers use smelled and smelt interchangeably***, and neither form is significantly more common than the other.
>
> For North Americans, smelt usually means (1) to melt or fuse ores, and (2) any of several small, silvery fishes of the family Osmeridae found in fresh waters of the northern hemisphere. ***Smelt as a form of smell is not unheard of in North America, but it is rare*** appearing mainly in the rhyming jocular expression whoever smelt it dealt it (and its variants).

Comment: But is this a matter of grammar or of spelling?  What would count as evidence one way or the other?

Answer (score 2):

***Smell*** has both an irregular and regular form. You can use both and both are correct. Brits use ***smelled*** and ***smelt*** interchangeably, but speakers in North America rarely use ***smelt***.

But which is the most used one? Let's look at Google Ngram Viewer tool which displays a graph showing how phrases have occurred in a corpus of books over the years.

[image]

Let's look at the current online media:

> New project to find out what Europe smelt like from 16-20th century –
> [BBC]
>
> Yaoumbaev told CNN he smelt something extremely unpleasant –[CNN]

Source: [en.learniv.com](https://en.learniv.com/info/en/irregular-verbs/smelt-or-smelled-what-is-correct-and-how-to-use-it/)

Answer (score 0):

If we use [Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smelled_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%2C%20smelt_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%2C%20smelled_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%2C%20smelt_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&case_insensitive=on&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csmelled_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmelled_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csmelled_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_gb_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmelled_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmelt_VERB%3A%20eng_us_2019%3B%2Cc0) to distinguish between American and British published books, we see that there was, until about 1980, a regular and historic advantage of about 50% in the frequency of **smelled** over **smelt** in both versions. However, after that date, the instances of "smelled" have soared.

The caveat is that Google Ngrams is not very good at distinguishing American English from British English, as can be see by a search for "color,favor" in British English - there should be no examples.